# Want one html table to be same width as another

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Consider this HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Two tables before</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>

    table
    {
      font-family: monospace;
      font-size: 15pt;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      margin-top: none;
      margin-bottom: none;
    }

    td, th { border-left: 1px solid #000; }
    #bottom-table { caption-side: bottom; }

  </style>
</head>

<body>

<table>
  <caption>Before: top table caption</caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>This is a row in the top table which should be about this long</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="bottom-table">
  <caption>Before: bottom table caption</caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>This is a row in the bottom table</td>
      <td>widen this</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

This file renders like this in Chrome:

[image: two tables not same width]

Note that the two tables are adjacent with no space separating them.  This
is what is wanted.  Note also that the tables are of different widths.  This
is not wanted.  Rather, it is desired that the width of the second td in
the bottom table row be extended so that the bottom table width becomes the
same as the top table width.  Something like this:

[image: two tables of same width]

The image above is a bit off.  What is wanted is for the tables to be of
exactly the same width.  Of course, ideally, the HTML/CSS to achieve this
would not require absolute widths, so that changes in the width of the
first table would automatically cause the second table width to change.
Also, I would much prefer a solution in HTML and CSS only, no JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fluid width for both tables where they must also be equal in width, set them both to `width="100%"` and then make sure they fill the same parent `div`. Then, they should always be as wide as the parent which you can make relative and fluid to the page.